# SVG viewbox is ignored when composing from js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm creating an SVG using d3.js that uses a viewbox.

From JS, the viewbox is ignored as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxhcU/1/). However, if I take the code generated by the JS and put it in as HTML, it renders using the viewbox, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8qeHZ/).

Why is the viewbox being ignored when defined in js, but not when defined in html?

Code as follows

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
  .attr("height", 400)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("viewbox",'0,0,100,100')
  .attr('style','border: 1px solid black')
.append('rect')
  .attr('x',0)
  .attr('y',0)
  .attr('width',100)
  .attr('height',100)
  .attr('fill','red');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Attributes in SVG are case sensitive.  Multiword attributes are defined in camelCase:

```
.attr("viewBox",'0,0,100,100')
```

More information can be found in the [W3C Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)

Comment: Fun fact is that `viewbox` (wrong, lower case b) worked for me when I had it in the .html file, but when I had the same `viewbox` (wrong, lower case b) in a React `.js` file then it didn't. Chrome 76.0.3809.132.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the reason is a simple typo -- it should be `viewBox` and not `viewbox`. It appears that (at least Chrome) corrects this automatically when the page is loaded.

Comment: Ugh. Right you are. Looks like I should have read the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute